# Foreach loop to get department name in powershell office365

Tags: powershell, foreach, office365

I am trying to get the department from a list of UserPrincipalNames

I am able to get this to work for a single user outside of the foreach loop. Its adding the loop where I am having trouble.

```
Connect-MsolService
$users = Import-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\users.csv

foreach ($user in $users){

Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user | Select-Object firstname, lastname, UserPrincipalName, department |Export-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.csv

}
```

There are 50 email addresses listed in the CSV one email address per line. With the first line being "UserPrincipalName"

CSV Sample Data

```
userprincipalname
useremail1@mydomain.com
useremail2@mydomain.com
useremail3@mydomain.com
useremail4@mydomain.com
```

Comment: What isn't working? I tried exactly your example and it returned results as expected. Please provide any error messages or explain what you expected vs what the results were.

Comment: The code as presented will not emit all users with the requisite information into the destination TEST.CSV. (In fact, the CSV will be empty with the code as given.) See my answer below.

Comment: You gave `Export-Csv` nothing to export

Comment: Yeah the `export-csv` was in the wrong place, but even without it I get the error `Get-MsolUser : User Not Found.  User: @{UserPrincipalName=user@test.com}`

Comment: you are using `$user` as your UPN ... but that came from importing a CSV. that means it will be an OBJECT with at least one property that has at least one value. what happens if you use `$User.PropertyNameThatContainsTheUPN`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the headers and some sample data from your CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think PowerShell - the pipeline uses objects, and you have a `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
Connect-MSOLService

Import-CSV -Path C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Users.CSV | 
    ForEach-Object { Get-MSOLUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName | 
        Select-Object firstname, lastname, UserPrincipalName, department } | 
    Export-CSV C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.CSV
```

Comment: With this I get the error `Get-MsolUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'UserPrincipalName' because it is null`

Comment: There is something wrong with your CSV. If it has valid data in it, and is properly formatted, it is not possible for `$_` to be null.

Comment: I have updated the question. I changed my CSV giving the first line a header of `UserPrincipalName` now I am getting the previous error of `Get-MSOLUser : User Not Found.  User: @{UserPrincipalName=useremail@mydomain.com}.
At line:5 char:19
+  ForEach-Object { Get-MSOLUser -UserPrincipalName $_ |`. I have run `get-msoluser -UserPricipalName useremail@mydomain.com` just to be certain the email address is in there and I do get a result

Comment: I figured it out. I did not have one of the lines typed correctly. Reading is hard I guess

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to lookup for data from a csv , then want to use them in a script and export scrip 's result in another CSV

```
# Importing MsOnline Module           
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService


#Import excel document containing our data ,Path "C:\list-email.csv" 
$ImportData = Import-Csv "C:\list-email.csv"

$Output = foreach ( $Data in  $ImportData )
{
    #Storing Email column data in $Data for each row
    write-host $Data.Email
        
    Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $Data.IONEmail | Select-Object UserPrincipalName,LastPasswordChangeTimestamp, Departement
}
#Output the array to the CSV File
$Output | Export-CSV "C:\LastLogonDateExport.csv"
```