# For each loop only outputting 1 line into CSV?

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm currently attempting to run a report to find all users within my environment who are active along with what licence they have applied to themselves. To do this I'm using the following code:

```
$Users = import-csv c:\users.csv 

Foreach($User in $Users){

$UPN = $User.UserPrincipalNam
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "$UPN" | Select-Object DisplayName,Licenses | Export-Csv -Path C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation

}
```

When I run the above without `Export-Csv -Path C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation` I get the expected outputted information the way I want, however, when I run this with the export option I get 1 user, not all of them.

Why is this happening?

edit: This is not a duplicate of the suggested question, the `-Append` resolved my issue where as their issue was resolved without `-Append`

Comment: You need to add the `-Append` switch to your `Export-Csv` command to not overwrite the contents during each iteration. The other option is to move that `Export-Csv` command outside of the loop so that it is executed **after** the loop finishes.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Once again, it's always something so simply that I end up missing - Thanks for this, this corrected my issue. If you'd like to submit it as the answer I'll mark it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreach loop to get department name in powershell office365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776300/foreach-loop-to-get-department-name-in-powershell-office365)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I disagree, different answers to each question resulting in resolutions.

Comment: @Matthew - the question is identical; the same techniques will work in both. There isn't necessarily one and only one right answer to the problem.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin but as the resolution is different I would argue it's fine to leave this as it is

Comment: @Matthew - I repeat, the question is identical. That is unquestionably the definition of "duplicate"; the fact that there are multiple possible answers to the question does not change the fact that the questions are the same. Please note that it takes other people with close-vote privileges agreeing with me that it is a duplicate; until they do, the question remains open and additional answers can be provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `-Append` switch to your `Export-Csv` command to not overwrite the contents during each iteration. The other option is to move that `Export-Csv` command outside of the loop so that it is executed after the loop finishes.

**Option 1: Using Append**

```
$Users = Import-Csv c:\users.csv 

Foreach($User in $Users){

    $UPN = $User.UserPrincipalName
    Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN | Select-Object DisplayName,Licenses |
       Export-Csv -Path C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append

}
```

**Option 2: Executing Export-Csv After Loop**

```
$Users = Import-Csv c:\users.csv 

$MsolUsers = Foreach($User in $Users){

    $UPN = $User.UserPrincipalName
    Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN | Select-Object DisplayName,Licenses

}

$MsolUsers | Export-Csv -Path C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```